# How to export the Audits Table for Pardot Prospects?

Tags: pardot

We uploaded a large batch of Contacts in Salesforce. These inadvertantly synched with existing Prospects in Pardot and overwrote some fields that we need in our mailing lists. For example, the company field.

I can see the original Prospect values for company in the Audits table for each Prospect record.  But I can only seem to do this one record at a time.

Is there any way to export all Prospect records along with their Audits tables? Or use the Pardot API to do this?  I cannot find any way to download the Audits.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way via API to accomplish this. I've also tried to have Pardot Support help me out here and they are unable to.

One approach (which is ugly) would be to use test automation software (such as Selenium/Cypress) and create a script that will have the automation software navigate to the Audit tab for each prospect, extract the data you are looking for, prepare a new correcting CSV file for import.